# How to make a request to sails.js controller without using sails.io client helper methods

Tags: javascript, api, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I'm developing an application using sails in which I have to connect from external sources. they can be IOS or android mobile applications or simply an external html client.

In that regard I cant't use sails helper methods to make web sockets request be handled by controller actions.

as I read through the sails.io client file i figured I could just use.

```
socket.emit('get' , {url:'/tomato' , data:{message:'pony'}} , function(response){});
```

to mimick the sails socket.get() function but it is not working.

sails log in terminal shows the following message : No session data returned, and an error was encountered saving session data for the first time: undefined.

Comment: I actually had to give up on sails for this issue in favor of using plain old socket.io, but I'll leave the question open in case someone actually knows the answer as I'm still interested in sails for another project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry you had to give up!  This is a fairly common issue that comes up around communicating via sockets with a 3rd party.  It actually has nothing to do with the Sails helper functions, and your usage of `socket.emit` to replicate the `socket.get` functionality is perfectly valid .  Unfortunately the error message for this case is (clearly) broken in Sails v9, but the gist is: you need to get a cookie from the 3rd party domain before you connect the socket.  This means making a JSONP request to that domain.  Socket.io can actually do that for you, although you may have to set `io.util.ua.hasCORS = false` manually before calling `io.connect`.  Or you can create a JSONP endpoint on the remote server and hit it yourself.  Either way, once you have that third-party cookie in place, the socket handshake should work fine and allow perfect communication between your site and the Sails server.

**Edit**

The `io.util.ua.hasCORS` method is not valid, as it turns out--it will cause a JSONP request to be made to the remote server, but the response won't have a cookie attached so it's not going to get the job done.  However, when the next version of Sails is released it will include a mechanism to request a cookie from the external domain, and will handle the connection automatically in the background within `sails.io.js`.  Also note that you need to set `authorization` to `false` in the `/config/sockets.js` file in your Sails app in order to allow sockets to connect from remote domains.

Comment: I`ll test this approach on the weekend. Another thing that felt a bit weird is that when I tried setting the authorization flag to false in the config/socket.js the socket connection would no longer work even in the same domain :/

Comment: Hm, `authorization:false` should work to turn off auth.  It should only deny everyone if you specify a function for `authorization` that returns `cb(null, false)` in all cases.  Could be a bug in v9, but I haven't seen it before.  I'll try testing it out if I get a chance!

Comment: It does not only deny everyone but throws an exception as its trying to set a non existing session on the socket I think. as I specified no function I think it might be a bug. I`ll try to replicate and report the issue on github.